# setTimeout function not triggering on first mouseenter / hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent, jquery-hover

**Overview:**
I am creating a menu that shows a div 'showme' when you hover over a list item with class 'showhim'. I want a delay when switching between a list item so I included a setTimeout function.

**Problem:** The setTimeout function is not being triggered on the first mouseenter event. If I remove the setTimeout function the mouseenter event works fine.
mouseenter

**Tried:**
I've tried mouseover and mouseout to see if it would make a difference. If I put my mouse over the span (the menu item name) the setTimeout function would trigger.

Also, when I put a border on the top most parent div and hover over the border before entering the 'showhim', the setTimeout function is triggered and the menu works fine. I have no clue why the border would make it work..

```js
// Fake these for the snippet
var isHomepage = false;
function isMobile() {
    return false;
}
// End of fake
$('.showhim').mouseenter(function() {
  if (!isMobile()) {
    var $this = $(this);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {

      $('.mastermenuitem').removeClass('menu-active');
      $('.mainmenuitem').removeClass('nav-active');
      $('.showme').css('display', 'none');

      // Expand Shop Menu Container
      if (isHomepage && !isMobile()) {
        var corecenter_width = $('#corecenter').innerWidth();
        $('#shop-menu-container').css('width', corecenter_width - (border_width * 2));
      }

      // Add active class to clicked menu item
      $this.find('li').addClass('menu-active');
      $this.find('.showme').css('display', 'block');
      $this.find('.mainmenuitem').addClass('nav-active');
    }, 150);
  }
}).mouseleave(function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <!-- setTimeout triggered when hovering over shop-menu-container border -->
<div id="shop-menu-container">
<div class="menu-wrapper">
<div class="showmemaster">
  <div class="showhim-wrapper"> 
    <!-- Trigger Element-->
    <div class="showhim"> 
      <!-- mouseover works the first time when hovering over the span -->
      <ul><li class="mainmenuitem"><span>Menu Item 1</span></li></ul>
      <div class="showme" style="display:none;"> 
        Content 1
      </div>
    </div>

 <div class="showhim"> 
      <ul><li class="mainmenuitem"><span>Menu Item 2</span></li></ul>
      <div class="showme" style="display:none;"> 
        Content 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Side note: That HTML is invalid. `li` cannot be the direct child of anything but `template`, `ul`, and `ol`.

Comment: I've turned your quoted code into a Stack Snippet in your question, making the absolute minimum changes necessary (defining `isHomepage` and `isMobile` and putting something to show inside the `.showme`). Works in the snippet, the problem lies elsewhere (perhaps in that variable and function?). This is the advantage of creating a true [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for your input. I solved the problem and update the original post with the solution. The problem was with the timer variable.

Comment: Answers don't go in the question. It's fine to answer your own question, but you must do so by posting an *answer*. See the [tour] and the [help] for more. But as this is extremely unlikely to help anyone else in the future, I would instead just use the "delete" link under it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**
I had 2 setTimeout functions that were referencing the same timer variable.

All I did was create another timer and the hover worked properly.

```
var timer; // setTimeout for Menu Close 
var timer2; // setTimeout for Showhim 

// TIMER 2
$('.showhim').mouseenter(function() {

  // Do something

    }, showhim_timeout);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer2);
});


// TIMER 1
function timeoutMenu() {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        close();
    }, menu_timeout);

}

function stopTimeout() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
```